# Parse LiveQuery Subscription doesn't receive any events

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I have configured a parse-server running LiveQuery on Amazon EC2 instance, on port 9091, with no proxy, firewall configurations made. It seems to be working fine, because we tested on React and using http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, telling that the connection was successful.

However on iOS, I couldn't make LiveQuery work, even though the handleSubscribe seems to be ok.

I've created a simple viewController to try it:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseLiveQuery

class StatsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func insertMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
        let message = Message();
        message.author = PFUser.currentUser()
        message.authorName = message.author?.username
        message.text = "Hello: \(NSDate())"
        message.roomName = "Test";

        message.saveInBackground();
    }

    var myQuery: PFQuery {
        return (Message.query()?
            .whereKey("roomName", equalTo: "2")
            .orderByAscending("createdAt"))!
    }

    var subscription: Subscription<Message>? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Registers the subclass
        Message.registerSubclass();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        //1) queries for messages, working.
        myQuery.findObjectsInBackground().continueWithBlock() { res in
            for msg in ((res.result as? [Message]))! {
                print(msg);
            }
            return nil
        }

        //2) try to subscribe and receive any information from the server
        subscription = myQuery.subscribe()

        subscription!.handleEvent { query, event in
            // Handle event
            print("any event, please?"); //no events handled after creating a new message
        }

        subscription!.handle(Event.Created) { query, object in
            // Called whenever an object was created
            print("any creation, please?"); //no events handled after creating a new message
        }

        subscription!.handleError { (query, err) in
            print("any error, please?"); //no errors handled
        }

        subscription!.handleSubscribe { query in
            print("subscribed")
        }
    }

}
```

I also tried the subscription using the code in the parse example, like in

```
func subscribeToUpdates() {
    subscription = liveQueryClient
        .subscribe(messagesQuery)
        .handle(Event.Created) { _, message in
            self.printMessage(message)
    }
}
```

Is there any mistake or something missing in the subscription process?

Thanks!

Comment: [LiveQuery Example](https://github.com/FredvanRijswijk/ParseLiveQuery)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am having the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: It worked when I used registerSubclass(). Did you try it?

Comment: I'm also struggling with that issue... No solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

try adding

```
   Message.registerSubclass();
```

before Parse configuration setup

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in Xcode 8.1 iOS 10.1 and It works.

```
let liveQueryClient = ParseLiveQuery.Client()
var newMessageHandler: Subscription<Message>?

newMessageHandler = liveQueryClient.subscribe(messagesQuery)
            .handle(Event.created) { _, messageData in
          print(messageData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the `print("subscribed")` work?

If so it's subscribed but the update, create, enter ... events are not happening.

Check the querying object's ACL. Set the client's hasMasterKey to true in beforeConnect.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeConnect((request) => {
    const { client, user } = request;
    if(!client) throw 'No Client';
    if(!user) throw 'No User';
    
    client.hasMasterKey = true;
    
    console.log(` BEFORE CONNECT `);
    console.log(` REQUEST :: `, request, '\r\n\r\n')
})
```